# Regex not matching in url

Tags: django, regex

I have designed the following url pattern

```
re_path(r'^api/refresh-token/(?P<token>[1-9]+\_[0-9a-f]{32}\Z)/$',refresh_token)
```

`1_6506823466dc409a93b83b2c5f3b7cf2` matches the pattern `[1-9]+\_[0-9a-f]{32}\Z`.

[image]

**But when i hit the url it is not found.**

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 15, 2021 - 02:10:29
Django version 3.1.7, using settings 'tokenproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /api/refresh-token/1_6506823466dc409a93b83b2c5f3b7cf2/
[15/Mar/2021 02:10:32] "PUT /api/refresh-token/1_6506823466dc409a93b83b2c5f3b7cf2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3279
```

Comment: It does not match if you add a slash at the end. `\Z` assumes end of the string before the line terminator, but then there is still a slash to match.

Comment: Just work with `r'^api/refresh-token/(?P<token>[1-9]+\_[0-9a-f]{32})/$'`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks it worked !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\Z` asserts the end of the string, or before the line terminator, but there is still content to match: the slash at the end, so the `\Z` makes it impossible to satisfy any string at all.

You do not need to use `\Z` at all here, since there is no multi-line, and `$` already matches the end of the line.

You this can implement this with:

```
re_path(r'^api/refresh-token/(?P<token>[1-9]+\_[0-9a-f]{32})/$', refresh_token)
```